# Matplotlib line chart animation

Tags: matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am trying to animate a simple line chart with 2 equal arrays. I've seen some guides online but honestly, I'm not sure what I'm doing here, am I close to the solution?

I'm looking for this: https://miro.medium.com/max/1126/1*j0LxVQPbwtQDpL17TH9gZw.gif

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
y = np.array([6,9,12,42,50,62,76,82])
fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(1, 8), ylim=(6, 82))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    line.set_ydata(x[i:])
    line.set_xdata(y[i:])
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=200, interval=20, blit=True)

anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
plt.show()
```

Comment: Two typos. `line.set_ydata(x[i:])` is of course  `line.set_ydata(y[:i])`. Same for the x-values. Et voila.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are changing the way the data is set up. And I changed the number of frames to 9 because the number of data is 8. In addition, I used PIL to create GIF images, so please correct it.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation
from IPython.display import HTML
from matplotlib.animation import PillowWriter

x = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8])
y = np.array([6,9,12,42,50,62,76,82])

fig = plt.figure()
ax = plt.axes(xlim=(1, 8), ylim=(6, 82))
line, = ax.plot([], [], lw=2)

def init():
    line.set_data([], [])
    return line,

def animate(i):
    line.set_data(x[:i],y[:i])
    return line,

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init,
                               frames=9, interval=200, blit=True)

# anim.save('basic_animation.mp4', fps=30, extra_args=['-vcodec', 'libx264'])
# plt.show()
anim.save('plot_ani.gif', writer='pillow')
```

[image]

Comment: @Mr.T I reviewed it again. It was indeed `frames=9`. Thank you.